# Add multiple simple OpenGL cubes to one context and set up perspective for the individual cubes

Tags: objective-c, opengl, glkview

I have a couple of cube shaped objects that I add to a single context, which is in my GLKView . Every single cube is a subclass of NSObject and have their own base effect respectively. I set up the projection matrix and base effect for every single cube like this:

```
self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc]init];

        self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(45.0f,0.95f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
        self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix, 0, 0.0, 2.0);
```

Now, it seems as if all do have a connected projection. I would like to see all of them from the front. However if I position them a little off then I can see the bottom or top of the cube.

Another thing regarding the lines of code above: I have to move my model view matrix slightly along the z axis to properly frame them. Can't I just move the projection matrix back a bit ? I tried several values, however to no avail.

The container set up looks like this:

```
- (void)setupGL {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    self.layer.contentsScale = 2.0;


    // Create default framebuffer object.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFrameBuffer);

    GLfloat coordToPixScale = 1.0;

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, self.bounds.size.width * coordToPixScale, self.bounds.size.height * coordToPixScale);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    @synchronized(self){

        self.opaque = NO;

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        [cubes makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(draw)];


    }


}
```

In the cubes array in the `- (void)glkView:drawInRect:` method I make all the cubes added to the array perform their `-draw` method:

```
-(void)draw{


    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 24);


}
```

Can somebody shed some light on this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a couple of cube shaped objects that I add to a single context,

First cenceptual error: You don't add objects to a OpenGL context. That's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL draws points, lines or triangles, and that's it. Everything higher level is up to you.

You want multiple cubes, each with ther own perspective? You draw them one after another, each it its own perspective setup.

> Can't I just move the projection matrix back a bit

The projection matrix is kind of the lens. You wouldn't yank of the lens off a camera's body, moving it around, keeping the tripod with the camera in place. The modelview matrix is called model-**view** for a reason. The view part is what resembles a camera in 3D graphics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer datenwolf. However your critique does not answer my question a bit. I am a computer-science student and I would like to learn OpenGL as it is not in my regular curriculum. OpenGL is very overwhelming in the beginning, so I hope you forgive my misconception. I did not really mean that I add the objects, they are drawn into the current context right ? It kind of seemed synonymous from an OOP point of view. So, could you elaborate on the modelview point ? I presumed the projection matrix is the camera and the modelview just an "object" consisting of lines and points.

Comment: And every cube that is drawn does have its own perspective, as you can see in my first piece of code I provided. Is that incorrect ?

Comment: @MartinE.: Hard to tell without the full code or more context.

Comment: Well actually datenwolf you helped me a lot by letting me be aware of my misconception. So what am I supposed to do to move the 'camera' ? That would be the solution to my problem, because I am desparately messing around with my 'lens'(projection matrix), moving it around and not getting any valuable results. So if the modelview matrix is the camera, how would I be able to move my drawn shapes ?

Comment: @MartinE.: OpenGL does not really have a concept of a camera. It's all just matrix multiplication. Think about it this way: You can mount a camera on a tripod and move the whole world around it. Or you can keep the world stationary and move the camera. Or you can combine things. OpenGL doesn't have neither a camera or a world. But by treating the matrices in a certain way, things behave as there were such things in OpenGL. The modelview matrix, is compounds a model transformation in the world, and a world to view transformation. Hence, model-view.